# Проблемы с сертификатом charles

Tags: android-emulator, charles

На эмулированном android устройстве, проходящие через charles proxy запросы приложений  выдают ошибку "certificate_unknown", хотя сертификат стоит на устройстве
[скрин1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5540.png)
[скрин2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osXIM.png).

---

И при этом chrome нормально себя чувствует и у него не возникает   "certificate_unknown ", если через него запрос делать)
[скрин3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX7gJ.png)
Может, кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Удалось решить в итоге?